# How to Inherited multiple class from different model in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have Card Model and it have three different classes in there, App, Figures and Item.

I have another model called Favorite Model which is going have similar classes like Card Model but there will be just extra 2 variable.

I'm trying not to copy the whole classes and paste it inside Favorite Model because it'll look like duplicated so I'm just trying to texted it from Favorite Model but some reason I'm not allow to extends only one class but not three.

Card Model

```
class App {
  String name;
  int id;
  bool showCards = false;
  List<Item> items;
}

class Figures {
}

class Item {
}
```

Favorite Model

```
class Favorite extends InheritedModel<App, Figures, Item>{
}
```

I'm getting this error so just wondering if there is a way to declare 3 paremeters.

```
The type 'InheritedModel' is declared with 1 type parameters, but 3 type arguments were given.
Try adjusting the number of type arguments to match the number of type parameters.da
```

I'm not really sure the way I'm trying to do is logically correct so let me know and correct me.

Comment: Maybe `mixin` is what you need? some example here: [Mixins in Dart](https://medium.com/flutter-community/https-medium-com-shubhamhackzz-dart-for-flutter-mixins-in-dart-f8bb10a3d341)

Answer (score 0):

I'm likely not understanding how your model hierarchy is set up, but maybe you could try some composition, such as:

```
class CardModel {
  App app;
  Figures figures;
  Item item;
}

class FavoriteModel {
  App app;
  Figures figures;
}

class InheritedCard extends InheritedModel<CardModel> {}

class InheritedFavorite extends InheritedModel<FavoriteModel> {}
```